# SetFetchMode is being ignored

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have the following criteria:

```
session.CreateCriteria<ItemDeliveryDetail>()
       .SetFetchMode("ItemDelivery", FetchMode.Eager)
       .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Id", 21932250))
       .List<ItemDeliveryDetail>();
```

This results in the following query:

```
SELECT this_.itemdeliverydetail_id AS itemdeli1_4_0_,
       this_.itemdelivery_id       AS itemdeli2_4_0_,
       this_.partitiondate         AS partitio3_4_0_,
       this_.amount                AS amount4_0_,
       this_.processed_by_rem      AS processed5_4_0_,
       this_.single_item_price     AS single6_4_0_,
       this_.bookingaccount_id     AS bookinga7_4_0_,
       this_.supplierinvoice_id    AS supplier8_4_0_
FROM   itemdeliverydetail this_
WHERE  this_.itemdeliverydetail_id = :p0;
```

As you can see, there is no sign of a join to `ITEMDELIVERY` as I would expect.

How to fix it?

---

The mapping of `ItemDelivery` looks like this:

```
mapping.CompositeId().KeyProperty(x => x.Id, "ITEMDELIVERY_ID")
                     .KeyProperty(x => x.DeliveryDate, "DELIVERY_DATE");
mapping.HasMany(x => x.ItemDeliveryDetails)
       .KeyColumns.Add("ITEMDELIVERY_ID", "PARTITIONDATE");
```

The mapping of `ItemDeliveryDetail` looks like this:

```
mapping.CompositeId().KeyProperty(x => x.Id, "ITEMDELIVERYDETAIL_ID")
                     .KeyReference(x => x.ItemDelivery, "ITEMDELIVERY_ID",
                                                        "PARTITIONDATE");
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the restriction? Just to test a theory, ta. Also can you also post the mapping bewtween `ItemDelivery` and `ItemDeliveryDetail`

Comment: Did you try to do a join between the two entities? It should do what you want.

Comment: @Rippo: Removing the restriction doesn't change it. The generated SQL is like the one in the question, just without the `WHERE` clause. Please see update for the mappings

Comment: @MicheleLepri: What kind of join are you talking about?

Comment: @daniel-hilgarth something like this (the join can change on your real needs):
`var crit1 = session.CreateCriteria<ItemDeliveryDetail>();
    crit1.CreateCriteria("ItemDelivery", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);
    var ris = crit1.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Id", 21932250))
    .List<ItemDeliveryDetail>();`

Comment: @MicheleLepri: Thanks for the suggestion, but this still generates the same SQL...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: it's not supported.

In fact, if you explicitly disable the proxy behavior for `ItemDeliveryDetail.ItemDelivery` there are scenarios that result in an (internal to NHibernate) infinite loop and a resulting stackoverflow exception.

EDIT, *long answer* (partly posted on comment below)
Eager fetching on Composite id properties is not supported by the ICriteria mechanism. I believe you can make it work using HQL (in general HQL is stronger on fetch declarations vs ICriteria).

The proxy behavior can be disabled as usual in your mapping procedure (either that be fluent or xml or annotations etc)

I remember trying my best to make it work on NH2 (and failed miserably) and as much as i know the relevant code has not been improved/changed in NH3.

P.S. I've been working with NH 4 years now. As nice as it may be there a *gazillion* things **not** obvious about it. Just look at the source

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your answer *at all*. What is not supported? Eager fetching? That is obviously not true. And where do I explicitly disable the proxy behavior?

Comment: Eager fetching on *Composite id properties* is not supported by the ICriteria mechanism. I believe you can make it work using HQL. The proxy behavior can be disabled as usual is your mapping procedure (either that be fluent or xml or annotations etc)

Comment: That makes it clearer. I don't want to disable the proxy behavior for `ItemDelivery` in general, just for one query. That's why I used `SetFetchMode`.

Comment: It doesn't really matter. I preemptively warned you about the case with the infinite loop in case you did it as a "final solution"

Comment: OK. I understood your answer in such a way that you implied I already did this.

Comment: Using HQL instead of the Criteria API did the trick. Thanks a lot for this hint!